# WordNet table explanation

Tags: mysql, database, semantics, wordnet, thesaurus

I'am trying to understand the table of WordNet database so I can use it in a machine learning project, I was able to understand the explanation of table that I found on this [Wordnet explantion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278219/wordnet-sql-explanation) but have trouble to understand the following:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9DFx.png)

Comment: Can you show what you installed, from where?